# Can someone explain how Interfaces and EF work in the following scenario?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I'm struggling to understand the role of Interfaces and Dependency Injection in a multi-layered MVC project.

I have two layers in my project: **Web** and **Core**.

**Core** has an interface defined for all entities "IProjectDb".  **Web** has an implementation of this interface "ProjectDb".

1. When does the interface in the Core project get used?  Do we give it the interface so that EF can access the database?
2. Is the Interface just a proxy that Core uses to access the implemented version, so that EF can access the real data?
3. If so, what role does dependency injection play here?  What dependency (core depending on web, web depending on core) are we injecting, and where, and why?

I understand that the goal of interfaces is to **decouple** projects for better testing.

Now, say I want to add a Service Layer to this project.

1. Assuming the Service layer manages all data access, I could move "ProjectDb" into the Service Project, right?
2. Web now needs to access Services... so I'm thinking that I need to create an Interface in the Web project, which gets implemented in the Services project.  In another question I was told this is wrong and that both the Interface AND definition should exist in the Services layer, which to me defeats the purpose of an interface.  Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Its not a programming question..Go to `http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/`

Comment: No, this isn't a rule, it's a preference.  Thanks for the constructive comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When does the interface in the Core project get used? Do we give it
>   the interface so that EF can access the database?

ProjectDb is one concrete implementation of IProjectDb so technically it's already being used. By having IProjectDb, you can provide a variety of additional implementations to support Unit Testing or possibly using a different data store for different deployment scenarios.

This requires that you provide a means to specify the implementation (dependency injection or explicitly).

```
public HomeController : Controller
{
    private IProjectDb _projectDb;

    public HomeController() : this(new ProjectDb())
    {}

    public HomeController(IProjectDb projectDb)
    {
        _projectDb = projectDb;
    }

    ...
}
```

This is not related to EF. Your IProjectDb implementation can use EF, but this way your Controller doesn't care what it uses.

> Is the Interface just a proxy that Core uses to access the implemented
>   version, so that EF can access the real data?

The interface is just defining a contract that implementations must abide by. Using the above Controller example you are able to use the `IProjectDb _projectDb` property consistently regardless of the actual implementation of `IProjectDb`. Again, this is not related to EF.

> If so, what role does dependency injection play here? What dependency
>   (core depending on web, web depending on core) are we injecting, and
>   where, and why?

Dependency Injection allows you to define the implementation of IProjectDb to be used at run-time rather than having a hard-coded implementation defined at compile time. The primary reason for having it is to support Unit Testing, but it's not limited to that.

> Assuming the Service layer manages all data access, I could move
>   "ProjectDb" into the Service Project, right?

Yes, but is also valid to put this in Core (assuming Core is a class library). I prefer using a class library as it will let you use the implementation in other places if needed. ie: If you needed to provide another Service to run background tasks on the same data store, you could just reference Core and re-use the same implementation.

> Web now needs to access Services... so I'm thinking that I need to
>   create an Interface in the Web project, which gets implemented in the
>   Services project. In another question I was told this is wrong and
>   that both the Interface AND definition should exist in the Services
>   layer, which to me defeats the purpose of an interface. Can someone
>   clarify this for me?

Creating the Interface in the Web project will create an awkward dependency for the Service that defeats the purpose of separating the tiers / layers. In layman's terms you are saying that the Service depends on the Web application and that shouldn't be the case. The Web application should depend on the Service while the Service doesn't necessarily care about who is using it.

The purpose of the Interface is to support multiple implementations of a defined contract and that isn't violated by having it defined in the Service project (ignoring the fact that the service project typically compiles to an executable that can't be referenced).

Comment: Now THAT is an answer.  Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, the interface is used to decouple the relationships between your `Core` system and the `Web` application. Assuming that you placed all your business logic inside the `Core` segment of your project, and have the `Web` application consume this business logic, interfaces represent the *contract* you want to expose (or implement) in your `Core`.

In response to each of your questions:

> 1 - When does the interface in the Core project get used? Do we give it the interface so that EF can access the database?

Your `Web` application is the one using (or consuming) your `IBusinessLayer` interface, exposing access to you data store (via Entity Framework).

> 2 - Is the Interface just a proxy that Core uses to access the implemented version, so that EF can access the real data?

Yes. But in this case you're talking about a different interface, the `IDataAccessObject`, implemented by a `EFDataAccessObject`. The idea here being that in the future you may want to switch to another ORM, like `OtherORMDataAccessObject` implementing `IDataAccessObject`, and keeping the rest of your project (`Core` and `Web`) untouched.

> 3 - If so, what role does dependency injection play here? What dependency (core depending on web, web depending on core) are we injecting, and where, and why?

Dependency Injection is just that: a way to inject the implementation for all these interfaces by registering a single concrete type, which you can configure and compute dynamically. Basically, for each,

```
public WebClass
{
    public IBusinessLayer BusinessLayer { get; set; } // <-- Dependency
}

public BusinessClass
{
    public IProjectDB ProjectDB { get; set; } // <-- Dependency
}
... 

public Main()
{
    DependencyInjector
        .Register<IBusinessLayer>().With<ConcreteBusinessLayer>().
        .Register<IProjectDB>().With<EntityFrameworkProjectDB>();
}
```

...

> 1 - Assuming the Service layer manages all data access, I could move "ProjectDb" into the Service Project, right?

Yes. Simply make the `Core` system a dependency of your `Service` layer,

```
public ServiceClass
{
    public IBusinessLayer BusinessLayer { get; set; } // <-- Dependency
}

public WebClass
{
    public IServiceLayer ServiceLayer { get; set; } // <-- Dependency
}
```

As you can see, the implementation of the `Core` layer and the `ProjectDB` are left untouched, and you simply moved the `Business` dependency from `Web` to `Service` and created a `Service` dependency on the `Web` layer.

> 2 - Web now needs to access Services... so I'm thinking that I need to create an Interface in the Web project, which gets implemented in the Services project. In another question I was told this is wrong and that both the Interface AND definition should exist in the Services layer, which to me defeats the purpose of an interface. Can someone clarify this for me?

This falls along with the previous question: the `IServiceLayer` interface is defined and implemented in the `Service` layer project. You use this interface to consume your services from the `Web` layer, but this is only a dependency, as such,

```
public WebClass
{
    public IServiceLayer ServiceLayer { get; set; } // <-- Dependency
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this helps a lot.  I wish I could select both as the answer